# Click checkbox to update progressbar

Tags: android, checkbox, progress-bar, android-sqlite

I am using sqliteDatabase to save my data.My app is a todo list that allows a user to enter a list of items that they want to do, every item that is added has a checkbox so that when the item is clicked the progressbar status should change from 0 to a certain percentage depending on how many items I have on my list. For example, if I have 3 items on my list and I click checkbox for 1 item the progressbar percentage should be 35%. How do I do this?
Currently this is how I was doing it but its not working

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          while (mProgressStatus < mydb.getAllItems().size()) {
              mProgressStatus = array_list.size();

              // Update the progress bar
              mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                  }
              });
          }
      }
}).start();
```

Comment: what do you mean with not working? Nothing happens ? or is there some kind of error in your logcat? (if yes post it)

Comment: You should have a integer variable which holds the number of checked checkboxes. Every time user checks e checkbox add 1 to the variable and calculate progress percentage using that.

Comment: It does not update the progress the checkbox is clicked

Comment: @Erfan how do I do that? please show me an example